# Split a vector by its sequences

Tags: r

The following vector `x` contains the two sequences `1:4` and `6:7`, among other non-sequential digits.

```
x <- c(7, 1:4, 6:7, 9)
```

I'd like to split `x` by its sequences, so that the result is a list like the following.

```
# [[1]]
# [1] 7
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 6 7
#
# [[4]]
# [1] 9
```

Is there a quick and simple way to do this?

I've tried

```
split(x, c(0, diff(x)))
```

which gets close, but I don't feel like appending `0` to the differenced vector is the right way to go. Using `findInterval` didn't work either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
split(x, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x)!=1)))
#$`1`
#[1] 7
#
#$`2`
#[1] 1 2 3 4
#
#$`3`
#[1] 6 7
#
#$`4`
#[1] 9
```

Comment: Can you explain how the diff() function works and what it is doing in this solution? The official documentation on the diff() function did not help me understand it.

Comment: The function simply calculates all differences between consecutive vector elements. E.g., compare `print(x <- (1:5)^2)` with `diff(x)`. Since OP defined sequences as values having a difference of exactly one, I check for differences different from one. Check out (with OP's data) `diff(x); diff(x)!=1; cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x)!=1))`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can make use of [Carl Witthoft's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884372/carl-witthoft) `seqle` function from his ["cgwtools" package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cgwtools/index.html). (It's not going to be anywhere near as efficient as Roland's answer.)

```
library(cgwtools)

## Here's what seqle does...
## It's like rle, but for sequences
seqle(x)
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:4] 1 4 2 1
#   values : num [1:4] 7 1 6 9

y <- seqle(x)
split(x, rep(seq_along(y$lengths), y$lengths))
# $`1`
# [1] 7
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 6 7
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 9
```